# SMARTY - простые примеры

Tags: smarty

Подскажите как заменить конструкцию на PHP на SMARTY:

1) `<?=$polls_types[$_GET['id']]?>`
Попытался сделать так:

```
{%$polls_types.polls_id%}
```

2)

```
 <? foreach ($polls_types['types']['main'] as $key => $value):?>
    $polls_types['types']['points'][$key]   - ?
    <? endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну там для начала нужно передать в шаблон данные. Вот так http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.assign.tpl

Потом по ключу, который вы передали обратиться в шаблоне.

Т.е. `$smarty->assign('Name', 'Fred');`

Теперь в `tpl {$Name}`

И я увижу `Fred`

---

Теперь с циклом

Для начала нужен массив

```
$array = array(1, 2, 4, 8);
```

Отдадим его шаблонизатору

```
$smarty->assign('MyArray', $array);
```

Идём в `tpl` файл, пишем

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$MyArray item=itm}
    <li>{$itm}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Увидим в списке все наши цифры из массива.

**UPD:**
Тогда в логике делаем так

```
$smarty->assign('content', $content['polls_types']);
```

В шаблоне можно через оператор разименования (.) обращаться к любому элементу.

Пример.

```
{$content.polls_id}
```

Comment: у меня глобальный массив $content['polls_types'] который передается в SMARTY и мне нужно из этого вывести в шаблоне $polls_types['types']['main']

Answer (score 0):

1. Сделал так: `{%$polls_types.$polls_id%}`
2. Жду ваших предложений